# Fastest way to fill Uint16Array with a single value

Tags: javascript, v8, typed-arrays

```
var a = Uint16Array(16384), n = a.length, c = 65;
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) a[i] = c;
```

Is there a way to do this faster? This is a typed array of two-byte per cell.

I recall `memset()` from C or `fillchar` from Pascal.

Comment: Fastest way is to request the spec to add second parameter to the constructor that becomes the fill value. Right now the fill value is always `0` but that's wasteful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, the new `fill()` method on typed arrays would be a natural candidate as it would fill the buffer internally at compiled speed, and therefor performance faster.

Unfortunately, this isn't the case. **[This performance test](http://jsperf.com/fill-vs-while-loop/2)** show that, at the time of writing this, a traditional while-loop is many times faster. Even when this test has a slight penalty for the while-loop.

In addition, `fill()` is **[only supported in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/fill#Browser_compatibility)** at the moment.

[image: snap]

So the fastest method using an Uint16Array only, and with best cross-platform support is doing:

```
var i = 0, a = new Uint16Array(16384);
while(i < 16384) a[i++] = 65;
```

Uint16/32 arrays are always memory aligned, so you could in some cases where the length of them match up on a four byte boundary, fill using a 32-bit array instead with a 2x16 bit value (refactor at will):

```
var i = 0, len = 16384, a = new Uint16Array(len), c = 65;
if (len % 4) {
    while(i < len) a[i++] = c;            // fill Uint16Array as-is
}
else {
    var u32 = new Uint32Array(a.buffer),  // shares the same byte-buffer as a
        len32 = u32.length,
        v = (c << 16) | c;                // make value span 2x16 bits
    while(i < len32) u32[i++] = v;        // fill at close to 2x speed
}
// use "a" here
```

Comment: (and of course, you can always do a uint32 fill upto where they match, and in cases they don't just do a uint16 for the last two bytes).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recomment to use the [`fill` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/fill) of TypedArrays:

```
var a = Uint16Array(16384).fill(65);
```

You'll have to benchmark whether it's actually faster than the loop, but it should be optimised by the engine (maybe they haven't implemented that yet, though).